# copy input to output, for string with one or more blank, output one blank

Tags: c, input, implementation

here is the problem
for example

```
in = "a    b\nab  c\ndd";
out = "a b\nb c\ndd"
Here is my C code

while(c=getchar()!=EOF){
  if(c==' '){
      while( (c1=getchar()) == ' '); // ignore all other contiguous blank
      putchar(c); // output one blank
      putchar(c1);  // output the next non-blank character             
  }
  else putchar(c);
}
```

Can I have an implementation with shrinked size?

Comment: In your output example, I think you're missing the `a` from the second line (so it would be `a b\nab c\ndd`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you remove only `' '` :

```
int c;
char space_found = 0;

while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF) {
   if ( (!space_found) || (c != ' ') ) { // if the previous is not a space, or this is not a space
       putchar(c);
   }
   space_found = (c == ' '); // (un)set the flag
}
```

You can change it to check for any white space with a simple macro:

```
#define is_white_space(X) ( ( (X) == ' ' ) || ( (X) == '\t' ) || ( (X) == '\n' ) )
```

and replace the `c == ' '` with it

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind an artificial limit on the size of a "word", it's pretty easy to shorten it quite a bit:

```
// pick your limit here:
char word[256];

// and be sure the length here matches:
while (scanf("%255s", buffer))
    printf(" %s", buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Attempt to read a character.
2. If the input buffer is not empty, output the character previously read.  Otherwise skip to step 6.
3. If the character previously read is a space, keep getting characters until you receive a non-space character.
4. If the input buffer is not empty, output the recently read character.
5. Go to step 1.
6. End Implementation

Sample implementation:

```
while ((c = getchar ()) != EOF)
  {
    putchar (c);
    if (c == ' ')
      {
        while ((c = getchar ()) == ' ')
          {}
        if (c != EOF)
          {
            putchar (c);
          }
      }
  }
```